# Why does Hibernate TableSequence decrement?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FooTbl")
public Foo{

  @Id
  @TableGenerator(name="TABLE_GEN", table="MY_SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME", 
        valueColumnName="SEQ_COUNT", 
        pkColumnValue="MY_SEQ", 
        allocationSize=100000, 
        initialValue=100)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="TABLE_GEN")
  @Column(name = "PK")
  private Long pk;
}
```

Whenever I store a stateless collection of these Objects, they get inserted into the table, but each Object has a lower primary key than the one that got inserted before it.  If I have enough of them, I will start seeing negative numbers in the pk column in the database.

If I remove the allocationSize attribute everything works(It defaults to 50).  However, I need a high number because of the number of Objects being stored.

Ideally it would be nice to see this as a built in feature in Hibernate where you could pass the allocationSize to an existing Generator. I don't suppose anyone knows of one that I haven't come across?

I cannot use Sequences and must use a TableGenerator. Does anyone have a workaround to this?

Update:

I have tried the following non-JPA usage as well.

```
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", strategy = 
  "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator",
  parameters = {
      @Parameter(name = "TABLE_PARAM", value = "MY_SEQUENCE_TABLE"),
      @Parameter(name = "VALUE_COLUMN_PARAM", value = "SEQ_COUNT"),
      @Parameter(name = "SEGMENT_COLUMN_PARAM", value = "SEQ_NAME"),
      @Parameter(name = "SEGMENT_VALUE_PARAM", value = "MY_SEQ"),
      @Parameter(name = "INITIAL_PARAM", value = "100"),
      @Parameter(name = "INCREMENT_PARAM", value = "100000")
  })
  @Column(name = "PK")
  private Long pk;
```

If I add the following line, I get a different error because it is looking for the default hibernate table.

```
   @GeneratedValue(generator="TABLE_GEN")
```

The error when adding that line is:

```
 Hibernate: select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
 ERROR org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator  - HHH000351: Could not read or init a hi value
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The hibernate configuration file currently has these settings:

```
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">250</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
```

Final Update:

It seems that the hibernate properties that were set were what was causing the erratic issues.  When I commented out the hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data, hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings and hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys entries things look like they're working (using the original JPA TableGenerator code).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds really strange. [Based on the code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/TableGenerator.java#L305), if you set the increment to a value higher than 1, it gets a different optimizer. I would try to override the "optimizer" option on the @TableGenerator annotation, setting it to NoopOptimizer . It should "reset" the behavior to the same one as if the optimizer is set to 1, except for the increment itself. If this works, I would try to contact the developers, to understand if this is a bug.

Note: you didn't specify which version of Hibernate you are using, so, I checked the most recent code on Hibernate's github.

Comment: Yeah, this sounded strange to me as well. I am using the latest release of Hibernate 4.1.6.  I'll try what you mentioned.  Thanks!

Comment: Will do.  I will try it out on Monday

Comment: I tried using the non-JPA version equivalent (before changing the optimizer) but I'm running into an error: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save().  I updated the original post to show the code I tried.  Would you happen to know why it's doing that?  All the values I entered are valid for my app

Comment: You still have to have the @GeneratedValue annotation, the other is just a complement.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. It's posted as a final update.  Thank you for helping me out and spending time with trying to resolve this erratic issue!